# Show default additional product attributes in Category list.phtml

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, list.phtml, additional-information

On the [Product view page](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/stellar-solar-jacket.html) you have a default tab 'More information'. In this tab you see attributes from the default Attribute Set.

I want to show those attributes on the [Category list page](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/women/tops-women.html?product_list_mode=list), under the Product Titel for example.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you first need to create a new module.

Add this block class to your module:
`/app/code/Your/Module/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php`

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Block\Product\View;


use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;

class Attributes extends  \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
{
    protected $_productRepo;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepo = $productRepository;

        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $priceCurrency, $data);
    }

    public function setProductById($productId)
    {
        $this->_product = $this->_productRepo->getById($productId);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This simply adds a method to the stock `Attributes` block that allows us to specify which product to use.

Now copy `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml` to your module in this location `{module_dir}\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml`.
Add this code where you want the attributes to appear (line 72 for after the title).

```
<?php echo $block->getChildBlock('attribute.set')->setProductById($_product->getId())->toHtml() ?>
```

Lastly create the file `{module_dir}\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml` with this contents:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Your_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Your\Module\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="attribute.set" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Tested in 2.1.2

Comment: Great, thanks for your explanation. So first I have to built a module like [described here](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/) isn't it?

Comment: Correct, that's what you need to do.